# Bitlocker not turning on: Windows 7 U 64bit

Tags: bitlocker

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit with TPM 1.2.  I originally had BitLocker turned ON with my C drive encrypted.  I unfortunately had to reimage my system, load the image back up and try to turn BitLocker back ON.  When I press "Turn On BitLocker" and UAC asks for permission (I am using the administrator account) and click "yes", the process hangs and then nothing happens - no error message, no BitLocker wizard, nothing.

All of the BitLocker options in GPEDIT are set to "Not Configured" so I don't believe there are any policies that would be preventing it from turning on there.

I was wondering if I could get some assistance figuring out why BitLocker is not "Turning ON" and am not able to encrypt my drive.

Thanks in advance, I would be more than happy to provide any additional information that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you re-imaged your computer you may need to open up the TPM MMC and re-claim control of the TPM.

- run `mmc.exe` as administrator.
- Add the snap-in `TPM Management`.
- Use `Prepare the TPM`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!  I am unfortunately not seeing "Prepare the TPM" under the TPM Management Console.  The options I do have are:
*Initialize TPM (greyed out)
*Turn TPM ON (greyed out)
*Turn TPM OFF 
*Change Owner Password
*Clear TPM
*Reset TPM

Comment: Diid you start the MMC as **admin**?  Try doing the clear or reset, then **restarting your computer**.